# Getting 403 Forbidden while broadcasting in laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, pusher, laravel-echo

I am sending broadcast notification using private channel. I am using pusher and laravel-echo. I have uncommented both

```
 Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
'Broadcast' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast::class,
```

in **config/app.php**.

I am using web routes and using 'auth:sanctum' middleware.

**BroadcastServiceProvider.php**

```
public function boot()
    {
        Broadcast::routes();
        //Broadcast::routes(['auth:sanctum']);

        require base_path('routes/channels.php');
    }
```

I have tries using both ways.

**bootstap.js**

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    forceTLS: true,
});
```

In request header, `Authorization: Bearer null`.
I have tried adding authoriziation token. But still, getting this error.

**channels.php**

```
Broadcast::channel('App.Models.User.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});
```

I am getting API message in my pusher account. But unable to listen it in vue.Below is the code in vue file.

```
mounted() {
    window.Echo.private("App.Model.User." +this.userId ).notification(
      (notification) => {
        console.log(notification);
      }
    );
  },
```

Comment: The 403 forbidden is coming from the initial request to the `/auth` endpoint, which can't authorize given your default configuration. The [answer should be here in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#authorizing-private-broadcast-channels)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, By specifying custom pusher authorizer, getting 401 unauthorized error.